# glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL) applying to all drawn objects

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

I'm developing a version of the Frogger game for a University project, and we got to the light and materials part. The problem I have is: when I set the materials for the frog, it applies them to all other objects that are drawn.
How do I make it so that it only applies to the frog? 
If I disable GL_COLOR_MATERIAL after the draw or after the material properties have been set, everything becomes red.

```
void Frog::draw(void)
{
    Vector3 _pos = Entity::getPosition();

    glPushMatrix();

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    GLfloat greenEmissiveMaterial[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

    GLfloat mat_ambient[] = {0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = {1.8 };

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    glTranslatef( _pos.getX()*U , _pos.getY()*U , 1 );
    //CORPO
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.5,50,50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.3,50,50);
    glPopMatrix();


    glPopMatrix();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Enabling the state `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` causes the material color to track the current color for the face you specify in a call to `glColorMaterial (...)`. In other words, while `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` is enabled and `glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)` has been set, the value of `GL_AMBIENT` and `GL_DIFFUSE` are determined *exclusively* by the current color for the front-face.

#### Thus, the the following call:

```
glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

#### Is effectively equivalent to this in your software:

```
glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Set the "current" color

GLfloat red [3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
```

You can see that you have changed the value of `GL_AMBIENT` and `GL_DIFFUSE` to **red**. And you also tried to change the ambient / diffuse material color manually while that state was enabled in your original code, which is not going to do anything.

#### The behavior above is described in more detail here:

> #### Name
>
> > **[glColorMaterial](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)** — cause a material color to track the current color
>
> #### C Specification
>
> > void glColorMaterial(    GLenum      face,
> >                              GLenum      mode);
>
> #### Description
>
> > **`glColorMaterial`** specifies which material parameters track the current color. When `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` is enabled, the material parameter or parameters specified by mode, of the material or materials specified by face, ***track the current color at all times***.
> >
> > To enable and disable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`, call **`glEnable`** and **`glDisable`** with argument `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`. `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` is initially *disabled*.

---

If you want to stop tracking the current color and use the values in `mat_ambient` and `mat_diffuse`, then you should add the following code sometime ***after*** you disable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`:

```
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
```